# how to select text color of numberpicker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, numberpicker, flutter-packages

I'm working on an application and I wanted to use the [numberpicker](https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker) package for flutter. But the default color for the number picker is blue, and I want to change it, how can I do that? Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two `TextStyle`

- `textStyle` : others than selected text(except middle one)
- `selectedTextStyle`: selected/middle textStyle

```dart
NumberPicker(
  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
  selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
  value: _currentValue,
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 100,
  onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _currentValue = value),
),
```

[image]